# Getting posted ID from Dropdownlist model which is not included in the modelview

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

When I try to insert posted information to a model which has direct relationship with "Banks" it works perfectly fine.

Code snippets for the direct model which works fine with auto-implemented CRUD operations

```
public class Organization
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ....
    [Display(Name = "Bank:")]
    public int BankID { get; set; }
    public virtual Bank Bank { get; set; }
    ....
}

public class Bank
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Bank")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.BankID = new SelectList(db.Banks, "ID", "Title");
    ....
    return View();
}

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Organization organization)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        organization.OrganizationStatusID = 1;
        db.Organizations.Add(organization);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.BankID = new SelectList(db.Banks, "ID", "Title", organization.BankID);
    ....
    return View(organization);
}
```

But the problem I face is that when I try to implement it with:

```
public class _OrganizationUserSignedBy
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

This ModelView it only shows bank information in Dropdownlist although when the information is posted via "Submit" button it gives me an error that bankID can`t be null. I tested if it worked if I manually inserted that all dropdownlist items selected would be 1 (ex:_OrganizationUserSignedBy.Organization.BankID = 1;) it worked fine. The problem is that posted information is not received correctly in my ModelView.

Modelview code snippets:

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.BankID = new SelectList(db.Banks, "ID", "Title");
    ....
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(_OrganizationUserSignedBy _OrganizationUserSignedBy)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _OrganizationUserSignedBy.Organization.OrganizationStatusID = 1;
        db.Organizations.Add(_OrganizationUserSignedBy.Organization);
        _OrganizationUserSignedBy.Organization.BankID = 1;
        ....
        db.SaveChanges();
        _OrganizationUserSignedBy.User.OrganizationID = db.Organizations.Max(x => x.ID);
        _OrganizationUserSignedBy.SignedBy.OrganizationID = db.Organizations.Max(x => x.ID);
        db.Users.Add(_OrganizationUserSignedBy.User);
        db.SignedBys.Add(_OrganizationUserSignedBy.SignedBy);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.BankID = new SelectList(db.Banks, "ID", "Title", _OrganizationUserSignedBy.Organization.BankID);
    ....
    return View(_OrganizationUserSignedBy);
}
```

Create View:

```
@model MVC_CPO_REGRELEASE.Models._OrganizationUserSignedBy
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    ....
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Organization.BankID, "*Banko pavadinimas:")
    @Html.DropDownList("BankID", null, "Pasirinkite...")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Organization.BankID)
```

Been searching for a way out of this for a week now and I can`t find the solution.. Any help would be appreciated and if you have any tips for now or the future I would appreciate it very much. Thank you!

PS: Some code was cut, so it would not take you too long to understand where the problem could lie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your creating `<select>` elements that have name attributes that have no relationship to your model. For example the first one is

```
<select name="BankID" .... >
```

but your model does not have a property named `BankID` (although it does have a property named `Organization` which appears to have a property named `BankID`.

Despite you claims, your first implementation does not work correctly either. You cannot use the same name for the property your binding to and the name of the `SelectList` (for example you will not get client side validation) and you should always be using a view model for views containing forms (and that view model would contain properties for each of the `SelectList` properties). In addition, you should not be binding to a property of a data model. If any of the properties of `Organization` have validation attributes, `ModelState` will be invalid.

Your view model should be

```
public class OrganizationUserSignedByVM
{
    public int? ID { get; set; } // so you can use it in an edit view as well
    [Display(Name = "Bank")]
    [Required(ErrorMesage = "Please select a bank")]
    public int SelectedBank { get; set; }
    public SelectList BankList { get; set; }
    .....
}
```

and in the controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    OrganizationUserSignedByVM model= new OrganizationUserSignedByVM();
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
}
public ActionResult Create(OrganizationUserSignedByVM model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ConfigureViewModel(model);
        return View(model);
    }
    // initialise a new instance of your data model(s) and save
    // redirect
}

private void ConfigureViewModel(OrganizationUserSignedByVM model)
{
    model.BankList = new SelectList(db.Banks, "ID", "Title");
    ....
}
```

and in the view

```
@model yourAssembly.OrganizationUserSignedByVM 
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedBank)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedBank, Model.BankList, "-Please select-")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedBank)
    ....
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```